# isContain function in a List

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement `isContain` function in Haskell, Following is my code

```
isContain :: Char -> Bool

isContain  x = if x== b then True else isContain   x where (b:bs) = ['a'..'z']
```

My code goes infinite because the value of `b` never changes. How do I change it so it changes the value of `b`. Please let me know how do I make it iterative.

I have other ideas to implement the function but I want to do this for learning purposes.

Comment: Well you should implement a recursive function using the rest of the values in the alphabet.  This means you need to pass the variable `bs` to a call recursively.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson for this I would have to change the value function signature. any other way possible?

Comment: Closing the loop: You already saw and accepted an answer how the suggestion needn't change your type signature.  Specifically, a helper function can be used which recurses over the list of values, `['a'..'z']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the updated list (its tail) to the recursive call. If you want to keep the existing signature, you still can define a nested function in the `where` clause:

```
contains x = cont ['a'..'z'] 
  where cont [] = False
        cont (b:bs) = if x == b then True else cont bs
```

Comment: could you please exaplain a bit, I am confused that where should I put `contains x = cont ['a'..'z'].

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I just renamed `isContain` to `contains`, it sounds more correct to me.

Answer (score 2):

You could indeed solve your problem by implementing

```
isContain :: [Char] -> Char -> Bool
isContain []     _ = False
isContain (b:bs) x = ...
```

passing a list of characters as argument, and dropping a character from the top of the list at each step. But you don't need to.

The type `Char` has an instance of class `Ord` which mean you can compare characters. So all you need is to check if your `x` is between `a` and `z`

```
isContain :: Char -> Bool     
isContain  x = (x>='a') && (x<='z')
```

Finally note this function already exists in the module `Data.Char`.

```
isAsciiLower :: Char -> Bool
```

Comment: This sounds good, but I don't want to change the definition of the class.

Comment: Nothing here is changing a definition of a class. What that is saying is that you can use inequality operators with characters (that is `>`, `<`, `>=` and `<=`), You can use inequalities for types with instances of `Ord` which is the case with `Char`.